# Adding property by hand to Base model in Symfony1.4 and Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have added a new field to my table `Empresa` so I need to change my model. For not regenerate the whole things meaning model-forms-filters I decide to add it by hand (manually) so I'm trying to add a the property to `BaseSdrivingEmpresa.class.php` as follow:

```
<?php

/**
 * BaseSdrivingEmpresa
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $umbralvoz
 * 
 * @method integer                    getUmbralvoz()                  Returns the current record's "umbralvoz" value
 * @method SdrivingEmpresa            setUmbralvoz()                  Sets the current record's "umbralvoz" value
 * 
 * @package    isecurdriving
 * @subpackage model
 * @author     Your name here
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseSdrivingEmpresa extends sfDoctrineRecord {

    public function setTableDefinition() {
        $this->setTableName('sdriving_empresa');

        $this->hasColumn('umbralvoz', 'integer', 11, array(
            'type' => 'integer',
            'notnull' => false,
            'default' => 60,
            'length' => 11,
        ));
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

> 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException

Any time I try to get the property to display it on a template:

```
$id_empresa = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
$this->sdriving_configuracion = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingEmpresa')->createQuery('a')->where('a.idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();

<?php echo $sdriving_configuracion[0]->SdrivingEmpresa->getUmbralvoz() ?>
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all manual edit of your `Base*.class.php` is not a good idea as this class is meant to be generated automatically and will be overwritten by next model build. If you want to do anything manually you should do it in direct child of `BaseSdrivingEmpresa.class.php` which is `SdrivingEmpresa.class.php`. 
Second thing is that better place for such modification is `SdrivingEmpresaTable.class.php`. I would suggest modifying `getInstance` method so it looks like:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    $this->setColumn('umbralvoz', 'integer', 11, array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'notnull' => false,
        'default' => 60,
        'length' => 11,
    ));
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingEmpresa');
}
```

Finally, I think that in this case best solution is just simply modify your `schema.yml` file, add your column and then use command

```
./symfony doctrine:build-model
```

which will rebuild your model without touching forms, filters which you mentioned.